# Substituting $y^2$ in a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I have the IVP:

$$2yy'+5 = y^2 + 5x; y(0)=6.$$

In order to solve this, I have attempted to make the substitution $u = y^2 \implies \sqrt{u} = y$. However, I am not sure how to solve for $u'$, so I don't know how to proceed in the problem.

I know that $\frac{du}{dx} = \frac{d(y^2)}{dx}$ but I'm not really sure what that means or how to deal with it.

Comment: As you do, set $u=y^2$, the equation changes to $u'-u-5x+5=0$, solve this equation and back to $sqrt{u} = y$.

Comment: @Riemann why does the equation change to this form? I think I'm not really understanding the math of the differentials. Is $\frac{d}{dx} y^2 = 2y \frac{dy}{dx}$ then? If it is, I don't understand why the $\frac{dy}{dx}$ stays.

Comment: you are right $\frac{d}{dx} y^2 = 2y \frac{dy}{dx}$.

Comment: $y=\sqrt{36 {e^{x}}-5 x}$

Comment: Why in the world are you attempting to solve a differential equation when you do not know how to differentiate?  Learn Calculus [b]before[/b] differential equations!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $u = y^2$, then by the chain rule
$$ u' = (y^2)' = 2yy'. $$
From your original equation, you see that $$ 2yy' = y^2+5x-5 = u+5x-5, $$ 
so that the equation for $u$ becomes
$$ u' = u+5x-5. $$
Also take care that the initial condition for $u$ then becomes
$$ u(0) = y(0)^2 = 6^2 = 36. $$

Comment: Forgot about the chain rule. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Since we have $u'(x) = \frac{d}{dx} y(x)^2 = 2y'(x) y(x)$, we can translate the IVP to
$$\tag{1} u'(x) = u(x)+5x-5 \quad \text{with} \quad u(0) = y^2(0) = 36.$$
Note that this approach only works because the intial condition isn't zero. The IVP (1) is an inhomogeneous linear ordinary differential equation of degree one and can be solved as usual.